# How can I kill a process in kernel?

Tags: kernel, process

I am interested in kernel development, and I am trying to find a way to terminate and kill a process. The only thing that I know is pid and task descriptor value of that process.

In other words, how can I kill a process by using its pid or pointer to its task_struct in kernel ?

Comment: When I write my question, I explicitly add the phare `in kernel`. I have to kill the process in kernel modules.

Comment: If your question gets closed you can try posting on Stack Overflow which handles mainly programming questions.

Comment: I think this question is more suited to StackOverflow because it's specifically about computer programming.

Answer (score 1):

1. The code you could reference is oom killer at mm/oom_kill.c

   https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/mm/oom_kill.c

   This is the mechanism when system is out of memory, kernel will choose some process to kill.
2. Android LMK is relatively simpler. It is using send_sig.
   https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/arm64/+/android-9.0.0_r0.32/drivers/staging/android/lowmemorykiller.c
3. Or you can use `int kill_pid(struct pid *pid, int sig, int priv)` function.